# imap_check returns no results

Tags: php, email, imap

I'm writing a PHP script which is supposed to connect to an Outlook email account, retrieve the attached images and display them on a page.

I'm using WAMP and I've set up a mail server using hMailServer with the help of [this](http://www.synet.sk/php/en/155-testing-php-mail-on-localhost-with-fake-smtp-server-hMailServer-and-outlook) article and it works fine.

But when I try to connect to the mailbox through my PHP script, it shows as 0 messages as  shown in the screenshot even though I **have** emails in my Outlook account's inbox.

[image]

This is the PHP code I've written so far.

```
$serverName = "{localhost/imap:143}INBOX";
//$serverName = "{localhost/pop3:110}INBOX";

$userName = "isuru@localhost.localdomain";
$passWord = "abc123";

$mbox = imap_open($serverName, $userName, $passWord);
if(!$mbox)
{
    echo "Could not open Mailbox";
}

$hdr = imap_check($mbox);
if(!$hdr)
{
    echo "failed";
}
else
{
    var_dump($hdr);
    echo "Messages " . $hdr->Nmsgs . "\n\n<br><br>";
    $msgCount = $hdr->Nmsgs;
}
```

This is the information regarding the mail account.

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

I made some changes in the code (updated it here as well) and now the output looks like this.
[image]

Still the original issue persists though. Showing 0 even when there are emails in my account.

Can anyone please tell me why this may be happening and what changes should be done?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($hdr = imap_check($mbox))
```

Since you're using just one `=`, it's probably not doing the intended operation. The following else will never be accessed.

Comment: I did as you've mentioned and it threw an _Undefined variable_ error for `$hdr`. So I made some changes in my code and updated it in my original post above as well. But the issue is still there though..